# rewriting total derivative using partial derivative

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

I have a function as follows $f(s,a)$ where $a=\pi_\theta(s)$ and I want to take the total derivative of f with respect to $\theta$ how would I go about writing an expression for this using partial derivatives?

I have two versions of what I imagine the expression would look like

$$\frac{df}{d\theta} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial s}\frac{ds}{d\theta} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial a}\frac{da}{d\theta}$$

$$\frac{df}{d\theta} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial s}\frac{ds}{d\theta} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}$$

I'm only really confused by the $\pi_\theta(s)$ since it is also a function of s. Does it make sense that we can take the partial derivative of $f$ w.r.t $a$ even though a is a function of s? (version 1). Or do we have to just take the partial derivative with respect to $\theta$ directly (version 2)

Comment: The second expression requires $f$ to be an explicit function of $\theta$, but it is not - as you defined it.

Comment: The good rule of thumb is that the equations must also hold in the case of linear functions. So suppose $\,f(s,a) = c_1 s+c_2\,a,\,$ and $\, \pi_\theta(x) = c_3\, x+ c_4.\,$ Then see which expression for $\,\frac{df}{d\theta}\,$ give the correct result.

Comment: Thanks both of those comments helped unmuddle my confusion. I think i was drawn to the idea of just substituting  $a$ for $\pi_\theta(s)$ in the function but then we've changed the parameters of the function to $f(s,\theta)$ . 
Is it correct in saying that $\frac{da}{d\theta}$ and$\frac{d\pi_\theta(s)}{d\theta}$ are equivalent? i.e the idea we can just "change" the variable notation mid chain rule